# React Native startup optimization

Tags: react-native

I am looking for a way to optimize the startup time of a pure react native mobile app.

As a JavaScript framework, is that possible to bundle the JavaScript files into separated files, say something like `common.js` and `app.js`. I was searching via Google with keywords something like "`react native webpack`" stuff but it seems like all these libraries are deprecated or out of date, such as `react-native-webpack-server`, `react-native-webpack-starter-kit` etc.

I am wondering if anybody here is also looking for a way to optimize the JavaScript bundle in react native. Or, maybe these third party bundle approach has been overcame by Facebook standard bundle?

Comment: You can always create multiple bundles and host them in different contexts. But you would need to bridge the gap between those different "parts" of the app.

Comment: @Moti Azu Thanks for your comment. There is no document for spearate bundle file. Do you have any link for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically load your component, in this way your bundle.js will contain only the fraction of js needed and as you navigate you will request the other different parts / fractions.

Rather than do the traditional way: `import App from './containers/App/App';` you could do something like this:

```
class ImportedComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        component: null
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.load()
        .then((mod) => this.setState(() => ({
            component: mod.default
        })))
    }

    render() {
        return this.props.children(this.state.component)
    }
}

const App = (props) => (
<ImportedComponent load={() => import('./containers/App/App')}>
    {(Component) => Component === null ? <h6 className="loading-message">Loading...</h6> : <Component {...props}/>}
</ImportedComponent>
)
```

or you can lazy load your component itself. Let's say for example that I have Moment JS and I don't want to load it until it's needed. so what I could do:

1) Create a state and set it to null.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lazyLoadedComponent: () => null
    }
}
```

2) Use async componentDidMount with await, try and catch and update the state lazyLoadedComponent on componentDidMount

```
async componentDidMount(){
    try {
        const Moment = await import('react-moment');
            this.setState({ lazyLoadedComponent: (data)=>{
                return React.createElement(Moment.default, {format:'MM/DD/YY'}, data) 
            }
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        this.setState({ lazyLoadedComponent: <div>{`Failed to load component: ${err}`}</div> });
    }

}
```

3) Call the component on the render:

```
{this.state.lazyLoadedComponent(value.createdOn)}
```

By following these 2 examples you should, hopefully, be looking at a bundle.js under 250KB.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution you can use `ram-bundle` format, that `metro` bundler provides.

In this case you will not load the entire `js-bundle` - you will load only part, that you need at a startup (in a lot of application are a lot of places, which user may not even see, and this feature allow you load such parts, only when they are required). So you can simplify your entry point and load only small piece of your bundle.

You can look at [react-native-bundle-splitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bundle-splitter). This library well integrated with almost all popular navigation libraries and allows you to postpone a loading of specific routes. For example, if you have a login screen, you can load at start up only this screen, and all others load in background or start the loading of them, only when user can see them.