# Error: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB)

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I worked with webpack for a white but to be honest I never paid attention to the build message(npm run build).

Now I started to learn a little bit about webpack, what does module, plugins, etc and I got to webpack optimization for production. When I run `npm run build` I get the warning:

```
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  main.js (478 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (493 KiB)
      main.js
      style.css
```

I have a file made for webpack for production

```
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          mangle: {
            keep_fnames: true
          },
          compress: {
            warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
            pure_getters: true,
            unsafe: true,
            unsafe_comps: true
          },
          output: {
            comments: false
          },
          toplevel: false,
          nameCache: null,
          ie8: false,
          keep_classnames: undefined,
          keep_fnames: false,
          exclude: [/\.min\.js$/gi] // skip pre-minified libs
        }
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, [/moment$/])
  ]
};
```

I used react-code-splitting in the file where I have the routes.

```
import Async from "react-code-splitting";
const Dashboard = () => <Async load={import("../components/Dashboard")} />;
const EditExpense = () => <Async load={import("../components/EditExpense")} />;
const Header = () => <Async load={import("../components/EditExpense")} />;
const Help = () => <Async load={import("../components/Help")} />;
const NotFound = () => <Async load={import("../components/NotFound")} />;
```

I used diff source map for production in webpack

```
devtool: isProduction ? "source-map" : "inline-source-map"
```

I moved all dev packages in devDependencies to not have for production too many modules.

```
{
  "name": "React Redux Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --config config/webpack.base.config.js --open --hot --history-api-fallback",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --config config/webpack.prod.config.js --env.NODE_ENV=production --progress",
    "start:prod": "node server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.3",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.11",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.5",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2",
    "react-code-splitting": "^1.2.1",
    "react-dates": "^16.7.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

My question: is this 244KiB the value that should not be reached to every project when you run `npm run build`?  My value is double that the default one recommended in warning.

If my value is too big what else should I do to make it smaller?

Comment: To reduce the size of your build, you can use minifiers, or reduce the amount of modules you need in your app. Keep in mind that your build will be what the client downloads. It is up to you to choose wether or not its size is good enough. Edit : you can also remove the sourcemap entirely in the prod build.

Comment: I'm to the minimum of the modules that the app needs to run. I created the project by scratch and when I need it something I install it. I use uglifyjs to minify  JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it's the moment JS library. I had the same problem. Follow the instructions I wrote on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630292/react-native-startup-optimization/51256736#51256736) and let me know if this help.

Notice that you can pass the props and data in this way

```
return React.createElement(Moment.default, {format:'MM/DD/YY'}, data)
```